# Error building from 5 to 6 IOS

Tags: objective-c, ios6

I have IPad application for IOS 5.1, now i'm trying to build it for 6.0, and get an error:

*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException',
 reason: 
-[NSFileManager copyItemAtPath:toPath:error:]: source path is nil'
"**

i found where is this problem, but i don't know how to correct it

in my **AppDelegate**

```
-(void)copyFileWithName:(NSString*)name Extension:(NSString*)extension ToDir:(NSString*)dirName withName:(NSString*)newName
{
    NSString *folderPath = dirName;
    NSString *filePathDocTxt = [folderPath stringByAppendingPathComponent:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@.%@", newName, extension]];
    NSString *filePathBundleTxt = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:name ofType:extension];

    //when i comment these two lines, my code compiles success, but i need these code
    if(![[NSFileManager defaultManager] fileExistsAtPath:filePathDocTxt])
        [[NSFileManager defaultManager] copyItemAtPath:filePathBundleTxt toPath:filePathDocTxt error:nil];
}
```

Answer (score -2, accepted):

well the error is source path for the copyItemAtPath method is nil.
Since you copy from the bundle (your app) to another folder that implies that the file is not in the target.

make sure the file you attempt to copy is there and correctly added to the target (in Xcode)

to resolve the crash add an if to exclude copying if the item isn't there / assert it

```
NSString *filePathBundleTxt = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:name ofType:extension];
assert(filePathBundleTxT);
```

Comment: Sorry, i'm new in developing for IOS, what should i do? Where is these bundle?

Comment: you mean file isn't in my project path, i think that i can't compile it in 5.1 if it was true, but i'll look, thank you.

Comment: well the error is source path is nil == the file can't be found in the app in this case

Comment: This does not explain the problem or offer a solution to it. It needs to be expanded in order to be useful; as it is it's a comment to the original question.